# Extract first paragraph using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract first paragraph. But I have found any luck. Can any one help me? here is text. http://dpaste.com/638776/. My text is dynamic. thanks

UPDATE: I'm reading XML file using eTree module. In XML there is tag called `<text></text>`. The data between `<text></text>` [is here](http://dpaste.com/639180/). I just want print following data from `text tags`. Is it possible? thanks

```
  '''Zamindar''' ({{te|జమీందార్}}) is a 1965 [[Telugu language|Telugu]] "Thriller" film 
  directed by [[V. Madhusudhan Rao]] and produced by [[Tammareddy Krishna Murthy]] 
  of Ravindra Art Pictures.This is variety role for [[Akkineni Nageswara Rao]]
  who is more popular with soft Romantic roles.He plays the role of a tough CID Officer     very well.The Movie has some Good songs.This movie has a considerable resemblance with the 1963 [[Cary Grant]] English Movie ''[[Charade (1963 film)|Charade]]''.
```

Comment: what do you mean for paragraph? Everythings from `{{` to `}}`? It seems a Wikipedia template, so if you use pywikipedia probably there is a better way.

Comment: @wiso its is wikipedia template. thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revised based on new info ...

If you able to produce the text between the tags, you just need to find a pattern for the first paragraph that will fit all cases, so based on this example:

```
 #data - stuff between text tags
 firstparagraph = re.search("}}(.*?)\r*\n\r*\n",data,re.DOTALL)
 print firstparagraph.group(1)
```

Comment: If you like post some details ... I'm still not sure if you're trying to parse the pastebin or just the text ?

Comment: Its working great. But at last I'm also getting warning message. `    print firstparagraph.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
. And I want only first paragraph so there is no need `{{Infobox film
| name = Bheemli Kabadi Jattu 
| image =
| caption =
| director = [[Tatineni Satya]]
| producer = NV Prasad, Paras Jain

}}` thanks

Comment: Maybe show an example where the regex fails so we can find a better pattern, keep ikuty's comment in mind too about the newline... and rubular looks like a great tool!

Comment: I don't know the Python language but I can see that you need to do an `import re` before playing with regex. Check the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you build a regex where the dot matches the newline, you have (tested in ruby but I guess that it will work in python as is). It is quite the same as the answer by Niall Byrne:

```
}}\n(.*?)\n\n
```

Please see the effect at [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/UqGQtFqOcz).